# How can I save the content of all txt.files out of a folder and store them in a list?

Tags: python, file, directory, file-read

I need your help, please!
I'm not a programmer, but I need this stuff for my thesis.

My problem is: I have a lot of .txt-documents all saved in a folder:

```
folder_path = "path/to/folder"
listOfFiles = os.listdir(folder_path)
data = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, '*.txt'))
allLines = []
```

I already stored my filenames in a list and joined folder_path with the path of each file. And created an empty list, where the content of the files should be saved in the end.

What I want to do:

```
for files in data:
        with codecs.open(files, 'r','utf-8-sig') as f: 
           text_ = f.read()
           allLines.append(text_.strip())
           print (text_) 
           print (len(text_))
           continue
```

Open each file out of the filelist in data, read it and save content in the new list. When I try to do it with the code below, it only saves the content of the first file in the folder. I understand that the problem is, that I can only define the name "text_" once, and that's the reason it doesn't work. But I read a lot of articles everywhere and can't find a solution for my problem.

Hope someone can help me. Thank you very much!

Edit: I need this Code from R in Python language:

```
folder<-"E:/Amadeus für MA/probe"
file_list<- list.files(path=folder, pattern="*.txt")
for (i in 1:length(file_list)){
  assign(file_list[i],
         read.table(paste(folder,file_list[i], sep='/'),fill = TRUE,sep = "#",fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
  )}
```

Comment: @JuliaLeschik--are you certain allLines contains the incorrect result?

Comment: Hey :) Yes, it just shows the content of the first txt-file in my directory. 3 times in a list. I might know where the problem is: If I write "for files in data", python just uses the fisrt string out of my data list, but I don't know why. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You were right. The Code worked perfect. I Just had 3 times the same data in my folder :D

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line:

```
data = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, '*.txt'))
```

to this

```
data = [i for i in listOfFiles if i[-3:]=='txt']
```

Rest of your code looks ok

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. But if I do the change like you suppose, then python isn't not able to find the path: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'DE2010000230-EA-2013_LB.txt', because fisrt I need to "match" folder_path and file_path. The problem is somewhere in the command "for files in data:". But I don't know, what to do different.